# Salesforce Connect - Compliance with OData spec on retrieving single record

Tags: lightning-connect, salesforce-connect

We are testing Salesforce Connect at the moment and it doesn't look like that Salesforce Connect actually handles OData requests of single records correctly.

For example, the [OData 2 specification](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) handles direct record requests in the format of `https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)`.

So in the specification we built, the following is the expected request vs the actual outcome we got:

- Expected: `/baseUrl/Record('12345678')`
- Actual: `/baseUrl/Record?$top=2001&$filter=RecordId+eq+'12345678'`

Is this expected behaviour of how Salesforce Connect retrieves a single record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting Salesforce Support, the Actual outcome presented in the above question is the expected functionality of how Salesforce Connect behaves when trying to view a single record. Since this isn't compliant with the standard OData specification on retrieving a single record, it is definitely something to keep in mind when designing an OData specification.

Feel free to reference Case #22201476 if you are looking to get clarification from Salesforce Support on the matter.